# When using the wikipedia's API's .random() function, why do I get an increasing amount of duplicate pages the more pages I get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using Wikipedia's API to scrape Norwegian content, cleaning it up and writing it to a file for use in training a language-model for CMU Sphinx.

When running the .random-function in a for-loop, but I am getting an issue though. I am counting the number of unique pages through the pageId, and I am getting a large amount of duplicates. In the beginning it's not too many, but after a while the count of duplicates is double the amount of unique ID's. When we've gotten 40 pages, we have around 80 duplicates.

Surely there is something about the .random-function we're not seeing?

Here is the code. The regEx is in functions for reading the filter-order easier.

```
import re

import wikipedia

"""
Module wikitest.py - Script for scraping Wikipedia of text based on articles 
found by using wikipedia.random.
    Used for gathering and formatting written text representative of the 
Norwegian language,
    for use in training language models.
"""

# Create regex to filter the results
specialcharreg = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-zÆØÅæøå0-9.,-]+', re.IGNORECASE)
whitespacereg = re.compile(r' {2}', re.IGNORECASE)
punctuationreg = re.compile(r'[.]+', re.IGNORECASE)
shortsentencereg = re.compile(r'(</?s>)([a-zæøåA-ZÆØÅ0-9,\- ]{0,50})(</? 
s>)', re.IGNORECASE)
isbnreg = re.compile(r'(ISBN)([0-9- ]{7,21})', re.IGNORECASE)
nospaceaftertagreg = re.compile(r'(<s>([a-zæøåA-ZÆØÅ,-]))', re.IGNORECASE)


#  filter-methods for formatting the text
def nospeacialchar(wikicontent): return re.sub(specialcharreg, ' ', 
wikicontent)


def nodoublewhitespace(wikicontent): return re.sub(whitespacereg, ' ', 
wikicontent)


def faultysentence(wikicontent): return re.sub(shortsentencereg, '', 
wikicontent)


def inserttags(wikicontent): return re.sub(punctuationreg, ' </s>\n<s>', wikicontent)


def noemptylines(wikicontent): return "".join([s for s in wikicontent.splitlines(True) if s.strip("\r\n")])


def noisbn(wikicontent): return re.sub(isbnreg, '', wikicontent)


def nospaceaftertag(wikicontent): return re.sub(nospaceaftertagreg, '<s> ', wikicontent)


# We only want articles written in Norwegian
wikipedia.set_lang("no")

#  initialize different counters for counting duplicates and uniques
idlist = []
duplicatecount = 0
uniquecount: int = 0
showuniquecount = 0

# define number of pages to get
for x in range(0, 10001):
    try:
        randompages = wikipedia.random(1)
        for page in randompages:

            #  get wikipedia page
            wikipage = wikipedia.page(page)

            #  get page ID
            pageid = wikipage.pageid

            #  check for ID-duplicate
            if pageid not in idlist:

                #  add ID to list of gotten pages
                idlist.append(pageid)
                uniquecount += 1
                showuniquecount += 1

                #  on every tenth iteration, print current unique count
                if showuniquecount == 10:
                    print("Current unique page count:{0}".format(uniquecount))
                    showuniquecount = 0
                wikicontent = wikipage.content

                # filter the content using different regex-functions
                filteredcontent = \
                    faultysentence(
                        noemptylines(
                            nospaceaftertag(
                                faultysentence(
                                    inserttags(
                                        nodoublewhitespace(
                                            noisbn(
                                                nospeacialchar(
                                                    wikicontent))))))))
                print(filteredcontent)

                # Write operation to file
                with open("wikiscraping2.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as the_file:
                    the_file.write('<s> ' + filteredcontent)
                    the_file.close()
            else:
                duplicatecount += 1
                print("Duplicate! Current duplicate count:{0}".format(duplicatecount))

    #  catch exception of wikipedia not knowing which page is specified
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as e:
        print('DisambiguationError!')

        #  continue to next
        continue

    # catch exception
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as d:
        print('Index error! (Page could not be found)')

        # continue to next
        continue
```

Comment: A couple unrelated comments: you're requesting for 10001 articles, maybe you wanted `range(10000)`. `showuniquecount` isn't really necessary, you can use the loop counter `x % 10`. `uniquecount` isn't necessary either, is equivalent to `len(idlist)`. `the_file.close()` isn't necessary because you're already using with-statement (context manager).

Comment: Hi Lie Ryan! Thank you for the tips! Will optimize the code accordingly.

Comment: A [more compact](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example might help.

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? If you sample at random then the more articles you take, the greater the chance that you'll already have sampled an article. It would take > 100 random choices to sample all 100 articles.

Comment: @smartse
Yes, but we were getting an absurd amount of duplicates compared to the amount of articles available. We partly fixed it though by using wikipedia.random(10) instead of letting it get one (1) page at a time. This lowered the amount of duplicates by a managable amount.

Comment: Hmm well maybe it's a bug in the wikipedia module. Could you just call the API directly instead? e.g. https://no.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=100